# Unable to authenticate iRedmail Ldap mail accounts with Redmine application

Tags: redmine, openldap, iredmail

I have two different servers for iRedMail and Redmine applications. iRedMail is using OpenLDAP internally to create email accounts.

I would like to authenticate Redmine application with iRedMail OpenLDAP mail accounts.

I have done the below LDAP settings but Login fails in Redmine application when i try to login with iRedMail email and password and displays a message as "Invalid UserId and Password"

iRedMail LDAP skeleton

```
dc=example,dc=com
-- o=domains
---- domainName=example.com
------ ou=Users
---------mail=testuser1@example.com
---------mail=testuser2@example.com


DN for testuser1: mail=testuser1@example.com,ou=Users,domainName=example.com,o=domains,dc=example,dc=com

DN for testuser2: mail=testuser2@example.com,ou=Users,domainName=example.com,o=domains,dc=example,dc=com
```

Redmine application LDAP configuration

```
Name - LdapRedMail
Host - IpAddress
Port - 389 
LDAPS - No
Account - cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com
Password - ******
Base DN - domainName=example.com,o=domains,dc=example,dc=com
LDAP filter - (&(enabledService=mail)(enabledService=deliver)(enabledService=displayedInGlobalAddressBook)(|(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(objectClass=mailUser)))
```

Attributes

```
Login attribute - mail
Firstname attribute - givenName
Lastname attribute - sN
Email attribute - mail
```

So would anyone help to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

After long search, i am able resolve the issue as shown below,

```
Name - LdapRedMail
Host - IpAddress
Port - 389 
LDAPS - No
Account - cn=vmail,dc=example,dc=com
Password - <vmail password from settings.py>
Base DN - o=domains,dc=example,dc=com
LDAP filter - <empty>
```